# Why I getting error while translate query to function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create function of existing `SELECT` query.

```
 SELECT uta.StartDate, uta.EndDate FROM user_timesheets_absence uta
 WHERE uta.UserID = 353 
 AND uta.Approved = 1
 AND DATE '2020-06-06' BETWEEN TO_DATE(uta.StartDate,'YYYY-MM-DD') 
 AND TO_DATE(uta.EndDate,'YYYY-MM-DD') + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

When I execute this query, I get correct result in output `StartDate` and `EndDate`.

But problem is when I write function and try to compile I get error

```
Error(724,8): PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression


FUNCTION GET_AVAILABE_USER_PER_DATES(p_userId IN INT,p_dateFormat IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS 
    rc  SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
OPEN rc FOR
   SELECT uta.StartDate, uta.EndDate FROM user_timesheets_absence uta
   WHERE uta.UserID = p_userId 
   AND uta.Approved = 1
   AND DATE p_dateFormat BETWEEN TO_DATE(uta.StartDate,'YYYY-MM-DD') 
   AND TO_DATE(uta.EndDate,'YYYY-MM-DD') + INTERVAL '1' DAY;
RETURN rc;
END GET_AVAILABE_USER_PER_DATES;
```

Compiler gives me error in following line

```
AND DATE p_dateFormat BETWEEN TO_DATE(uta.StartDate,'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

I try to understand what I made wrong, where is mistake but I couldn't ?
What is wrong here ? What i make wrong can someone tell me ?

**UPDATE**

```
FUNCTION ABSENCE_EXIST_FOR_DATE(p_userId IN INT,p_dateFormat IN DATE)
    RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS 
    rc  SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
OPEN rc FOR
    SELECT uta.StartDate, uta.EndDate FROM user_timesheets_absence uta
    WHERE uta.UserID = p_userId 
    AND uta.Approved = 1
    AND  p_dateFormat BETWEEN TO_DATE(uta.StartDate,'YYYY-MM-DD') 
    AND TO_DATE(uta.EndDate,'YYYY-MM-DD') + INTERVAL '1' DAY;
RETURN rc;
END ABSENCE_EXIST_FOR_DATE;
```

Error gone, but unfortunetlly when I execute function I get error message

```
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
*Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
           the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
           "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
           with no extra whitespace.
*Action:   Correct the format string to match the literal.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must replace

```
DATE p_dateFormat
```

with the appropriate conversion of the `VARCHAR2` parameter `p_dateFormat` to the DATE type

```
to_char(p_dateFormat,'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Adapt the the format if appropriate or use `DATE` parameter in the function.

Than you would simple constraint

```
FUNCTION GET_AVAILABE_USER_PER_DATES(p_userId IN INT,p_dateFormat IN DATE)
...

AND  p_dateFormat BETWEEN TO_DATE(uta.StartDate,'YYYY-MM-DD') 
AND TO_DATE(uta.EndDate,'YYYY-MM-DD') + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

Check if the name `p_dateFormat` is the best possible name for a parameter with a `DATE` value (or a string with a DATE value) ...

To avoid `ORA-01861: literal does not match format string` use the [`ON CONVERSION ERROR`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html#GUID-D226FA7C-F7AD-41A0-BB1D-BD8EF9440118) clause as follows (Oracle 12 and up is required)

```
FUNCTION GET_AVAILABE_USER_PER_DATES(p_userId IN INT,p_dateFormat IN DATE)
...

AND  p_dateFormat BETWEEN TO_DATE(uta.StartDate default null on conversion error,'YYYY-MM-DD') 
AND TO_DATE(uta.EndDate default null on conversion error,'YYYY-MM-DD') + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

If the column `EndDate` or `StartDate` contain invalid data, such as `today` or `2020-99-01` the conversion will not fail with error, but returns `null`, is the record will *not* be selected (which is probably what you want).

Comment: There is no `ORA-doesn't work` please be more specific... @don_julian

Comment: I updated my question. You can check UPDATE section

Comment: Check the data type and values in `uta.StartDate` and `uta.EndDate`

Comment: `ŞtartDate` and `EndDate` are `VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)`

Comment: updated with `ON CONVERSION ERROR` @don_julian

Comment: "ŞtartDate and EndDate are VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) "  Then you have a serious design flaw. Dates should _never_ be stored as anything but DATE or one of the variants of TIMESTAMP.  If you store a date as a string (varchar) then you will have to convert it using to_date in order to do any date math/comparisions.  But since it is a string, you cannot guarantee its format, so there is no reliable way to use a to_date on it. This lack of control on format is highlighted by the fact that it is varchar2(50).  What legitimate character representation of a date needs 50 characters?